# Importing text to MySQL: strange format

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I'm importing some data from a .txt file into a MySQL database table, using mysqlimport. It seems to import OK (no error messages) but looks very odd when displayed, and can't be searched as expected.

Here are the details. The original text file is saved in UTF-8, with records that look (in a text editor) like this. The second field includes line breaks:

```
WAR-16,52 ~~~~~ Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
~~~~~ ENDOFRECORD
WAR-16,53~~~~~Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit.

~~~~~ ENDOFRECORD
```

The database table into which I am importing is very simple:

```
+-------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| text  | varchar(5000) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I import the file, here's the command I use:

```
$ mysqlimport -u root db textfile.txt --fields-terminated-by="~~~~~" --lines-terminated-by="ENDOFTHELINE" --default-character-set='utf8'
db.records_list: Records: 18778  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 18787
```

Here's what I see if I then ask MySQL to display the records:

```
mysql> select * from textfile;
| 
 W A R - 1 6 , 5 2 |  L o r e m  i p s u m  d o l o r  s i t .
L o r e m  i p s u m  d o l o r  s i t .
(etc)
```

So, it looks as though spaces, or some strange encoding extras, are being added to the text.

And here's the problem with the database query:

```
mysql> select * from textfile where id like "%WAR%";
```

returns nothing; nor does adding spaces:

```
mysql> select * from textfile where id like "%W A R%";
```

Only this command returns anything

```
mysql> select * from textfile where id like "%W%";
```

Can anyone guess what might be happening? I feel like it must be an encoding problem, but I can't work it out.

------ UPDATE --------

OK, I've checked the database and connection encoding.

```
mysql> show variables like "character_set_%";
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                  |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                                 |
| character_set_connection | latin1                                 |
| character_set_database   | latin1                                 |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                 |
| character_set_results    | latin1                                 |
| character_set_server     | latin1                                 |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                   |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/local/mysql/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

And `show table status` says the table is `latin1_swedish_ci`.

I have re-saved the text file in "Western (Windows Latin 1)" (using TextEdit on Snow Leopard) and tried to import it using the same command as above. However I still have the same encoding problem.

I also tried, again with no luck:

- creating a new table with UTF-8 and importing the existing file
- copying & pasting the text into another text file that I've previously imported fine, and trying to import that.

Still totally baffled :(((

Answer (score 0):

As noted in your duplicate question, make sure that your table and connection are both using UTF-8. That is one of the common sources of this issue.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode.html

Comment: Thank you. I have checked this and updated above, but no luck yet... is there anything obvious that I'm still missing?

Comment: If the character encoding set is defined correctly, then the only other suggestion is to ensure that the terminal you are working in is also UTF-8 (if you are copy/pasting the statements). Otherwise, sorry, I've no other suggestions.